# Setting up simple web application service and testing - Linux debian 10

Tags: linux

I am doing my assignment given by the lecturer. On the title stated, my idea is about setting up a mail server on the server and we can send the email from the client, all the email is stored in the server virtual machine. Do my idea is correct on this title stated or any recommendations?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You might try asking on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) instead.

Comment: AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

- Sending mail is not that hard, especially just using (E)SMTP, tcp
  text dialogs.  Or you can use Linux mail commands.
- Storing mail, either locally or accessing mail on a pop or imap server, poses
  another set of challenges.
- And of course, you need the HTML web pages as well as the services.
- Attaching files can be another challenge, both uploading the files
  and encoding them for inclusion in the mail.
- JAVAScript can make some usual features of email clients easier, like sorting a list of emails in a folder or from a search by a column ascending or descending.
- Searching email is an even bigger challenge!